# Is it possible to display months between two dates in sql using a single select statement without using temp tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Months between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885851/months-between-two-dates)

I have date range as `[start date] = '2012-09-01'` and `[finish date] = '2014-01-01'`
Now, I need to display months between two dates..using a single select statement

```
Expected Output :          
9
10
11
12
1
2
3
.
.
.
12
1
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can user table variables also:

```
DECLARE @startdt DATETIME, @enddt DATETIME
SELECT @startdt =  '2012-09-01', @enddt =  '2014-01-01'

DECLARE @Months TABLE (Months INT)

INSERT INTO @Months VALUES (MONTH(@startdt))
WHILE @startdt < @enddt
BEGIN
 SET  @startdt = DATEADD(MONTH,1,@startdt)
 INSERT INTO @Months VALUES (MONTH(@startdt))
END

SELECT * FROM @Months
```

Comment: Shall i get it through a single select statement...without using temp tables

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @StartDate  DATETIME,
        @EndDate    DATETIME;

SELECT   @StartDate = '20120901'        
        ,@EndDate   = '20140101';

;WITH MONTHS (date)
AS
(
    SELECT @StartDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,1,date)
    FROM MONTHS
    WHERE DATEADD(MONTH,1,date)<=@EndDate
)
SELECT MONTH(date) AS MONTH FROM MONTHS
```

Result:

```
MONTH
-----------
9
10
11
12
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
1

(17 row(s) affected)
```

EDIT:
As per your updated requirement you can achieve this using following query:

```
DECLARE @StartDate  DATETIME,
        @EndDate    DATETIME;

SELECT   @StartDate = '20120901'        
        ,@EndDate   = '20140101';


SELECT  MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, x.number, @StartDate)) AS Months
FROM    master.dbo.spt_values x
WHERE   x.type = 'P'        
AND     x.number <= DATEDIFF(MONTH, @StartDate, @EndDate);
```

Result:

```
Months
-----------
9
10
11
12
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
1

(17 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: Shall i get it through a single select statement...without using temp tables