# Finding months between given dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Months between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885851/months-between-two-dates)

I need to bring the result ,what are the months falls between two dates.

Eg. Suppose date is

```
Declare @FrDate datetime,@ToDate datetime
Set @FrDate ='2010-05-31 17:38:58.577' 
Set @ToDate ='2010-09-01 17:38:58.577'
```

need Output

```
Result
MAY
JUN
JUL
AUG
SEP
```

Comment: A date dimension table would make this problem simple...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
DECLARE @FrDate  DATETIME,
        @ToDate    DATETIME;

Set @FrDate ='2010-05-31 17:38:58.577' 
Set @ToDate ='2010-09-01 17:38:58.577'

;WITH MONTHS (date)
AS
(
    SELECT @FrDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(month,1,date)
    from months
    where date<=@ToDate
)
SELECT Datename(month,date) AS MONTH FROM MONTHS
```

Result:

```
MONTH
-----------------
May
June
July
August
September

(5 row(s) affected)
```

To get short month name in result you can use the following line instead:

```
SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,date,100),3) AS MONTH FROM MONTHS
```

To get month name in UPPER case you can use `UPPER` function for that:

```
SELECT UPPER(LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,date,100),3)) AS MONTH FROM MONTHS
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a [calendar table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459260/calendar-table-week-number-of-month), then you can simply write this:

```
select distinct MonthName
from dbo.Calendar
where BaseDate between @StartDate and @EndDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method

```
Declare @FrDate datetime,@ToDate datetime 
Set @FrDate ='2010-05-31 17:38:58.577'  
Set @ToDate ='2010-09-01 17:38:58.577' 

select 
    datename(month,dateadd(month,number-1,@FrDate)) as month_name
from 
    master..spt_values 
where 
    type='p'and number between 1 and datediff(month,@frdate,@todate)+1
```