# SQL Query to print month list of no records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have written a query to get all the records from ORDERS Table of Northwind DB,

```
select count(*) as COUN,month(OrderDate) as Mon
from orders 
where  Year(OrderDate) = '1996' 
group by month(OrderDate)
```

Here I want to print all the months which do not have any record.
any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: The best solution is to have a dates table.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
select count(*) as COUN,month(OrderDate) as Mon
from orders 
where  Year(OrderDate) = '1996' 
AND NOT month(OrderDate) IN(SELECT month(OrderDate) from Orders WHERE Year(OrderDate) = '1996')
group by month(OrderDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could to use a `WITH`-series to generate those months you are interested in:

```
WITH mons AS
  (
    SELECT  1 AS num
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  num + 1
    FROM    mons
    WHERE   num < 12
  )
SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT, num
  FROM mons
  LEFT JOIN orders ON MONTH(OrderDate) = num
  WHERE YEAR(OrderDate) = '1996'
  GROUP BY num;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a having clause to avoid querying the Orders table twice:

```
select count(*) as COUN,month(OrderDate) as Mon
from orders 
where  Year(OrderDate) = '1996' 
group by month(OrderDate)
having count(*) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7885939/2505574) answer, you can try the below:

```
--Example Setup
CREATE TABLE FORDERS (OrderDate datetime)

INSERT INTO FORDERS (OrderDate)
    VALUES (GETDATE());

--Actual Query.
DECLARE @Year varchar(4) = 1996;

DECLARE @StartDate  datetime = @Year + '0101',
        @EndDate    datetime = @Year + '1231';


SELECT  DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, x.number, @StartDate)) AS MonthName, COUNT(OrderDate)
FROM    master.dbo.spt_values x
    LEFT JOIN FOrders ON x.number = MONTH(OrderDate)
        AND YEAR(OrderDate) = @Year
WHERE   x.type = 'P'        
AND     x.number <= DATEDIFF(MONTH, @StartDate, @EndDate)
GROUP BY x.number, MONTH(OrderDate)
HAVING COUNT(OrderDate) = 0;
```