# How to create Temp Table with month columns based on date parameters?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that accepts two Dates.  In my stored procedure, I need to create a temp table with the months in between the two dates as columns.

For example,

If the user passes in

```
1/1/2016 , 8/1/2016
```

I need a temp table with the columns:

```
January February March April May June July August
```

How could I create this type of temp table with columns created in this manner? With the columns being based on the two dates passed in?

Comment: what is you database system, add the tag!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Months between two dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885851/months-between-two-dates)

Comment: @TabAlleman This is not the answer for the issue i'm trying to figure out

Comment: @tab The difference is that he needs to create a temp table based off the parameters, not just output the month names

Comment: Oh I see, you need columns, not rows.   Ok, then you need to do this with Dynamic SQL.   You can use the answer in the other question to build your dynamic sql string.

Comment: @Reeggiie: what do you need in case when dates are from different years? Suppose 1/1/2010, 8/1/2016?

Answer (score 0):

The following script should get you started (and almost there):

```
declare @start_date DATE = '20160101' 
declare @end_date DATE = '20160801'

;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT @start_date AS cte_start_date, DATENAME(month, @start_date) AS Name,
        CAST(' ALTER TABLE #myTemp ADD ' + DATENAME(month, @start_date) + ' INT ' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) AS VARCHAR(8000)) AS SqlStr
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, 1, cte_start_date), DATENAME(month, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, cte_start_date)) AS Name, 
        CAST(SqlStr + ' ALTER TABLE #myTemp ADD ' + DATENAME(month, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, cte_start_date)) + ' INT ' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) AS VARCHAR(8000))
    FROM CTE
    WHERE DATEADD(MONTH, 1, cte_start_date) <= @end_date   
)
SELECT cte_start_date, Name, SqlStr 
FROM CTE
```

Using a recursive-CTE it generates a loop between start and end date, and for each month it computes its string representation and also creates a alter script to add the columns to a temporary table.

The CTE computes the SQL script gradually, so that the final script is on the last line.

Answer (score 0):

Try This ....

```
declare @start_date DATE = '20160101' 
declare @end_date DATE = '20160801'

;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT @start_date AS cte_start_date, DATENAME(month, @start_date) AS NAME , 0 AS Coun
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, 1, cte_start_date), DATENAME(month, DATEADD(MONTH, 1, cte_start_date)) AS NAME , 0 AS Coun
    FROM CTE
    WHERE DATEADD(MONTH, 1, cte_start_date) <= @end_date   
)

SELECT  Coun,Name
INTO #tmp1
FROM CTE

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + Name 
                 from #tmp1

        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT ' + @cols + ' from 
         (
            select Coun,Name
            from #tmp1
        ) x
        pivot 
        (
            MAX(Coun)
            for Name in (' + @cols + ')
        ) p '

execute(@query);
DROP TABLE #tmp1
```

It Will Return OutPut Like your expected output .......