# return the month in between sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to ask is there any way in PL/SQL that I can return the months in between user input.
For example, the user put in

```
DateStart: 01/2019   and
DateEnd: 05/2019
```

The query should return

```
01/2019, 02/2019, 03/2019, 04/2019,05/2019.
```

Comment: This post from Stackoverflow might help your query . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885851/months-between-two-dates]

Comment: Of course there is a way to do this. This is like the main purpose of SQL.
Also depends if you are querying a table or if you want a script to just output the above.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in sql, no pl/sql needed for this. 
Convert month/year to a date, 1st of the month.

Then count the months between the first and last argument.

Then select doing a connect by level + 2 (because you're including the boundary values). All put together this gives:

```
WITH test_data (monthyear_start, monthyear_end) AS
(
  SELECT '01/2019', '05/2019' FROM DUAL
),
monthcount(months) AS
(
  SELECT MONTHS_BETWEEN(TO_DATE('01/'||monthyear_end,'DD/MM/YYYY'),TO_DATE('01/'||monthyear_start,'DD/MM/YYYY')) FROM test_data
)
SELECT TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('01/'||monthyear_start,'DD/MM/YYYY'),LEVEL - 1),'MM/YYYY')  FROM test_data, monthcount
CONNECT BY LEVEL < months + 2;

01/2019
02/2019
03/2019
04/2019
05/2019
```

Answer (score 0):

You can firstly use `connect by level <=` syntax, and then apply `listagg()` function to concatenate the strings :

```
with t2 as
(
select distinct to_char( to_date(DateStart,'mm/yyyy') + level - 1 , 'mm/yyyy') as mnt 
  from t
 connect by level <= to_date(DateEnd,'mm/yyyy') - to_date(DateStart,'mm/yyyy') + 1 
)
select listagg(mnt,',') within group 
       (order by to_number(substr(mnt,-4)||substr(mnt,1,2))) as "Months"
  from t2
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=00242d10a482acd5577c524dd95d6251)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Similar, but yet different, maybe even simpler than previous suggestions:

```
SQL> with test (dstart, dend) as
  2    (select '01/2019', '05/2019' from dual)
  3  select to_char(add_months(to_date(dstart, 'mm/yyyy'), level - 1), 'mm/yyyy') result
  4  from test
  5  connect by
  6    level <= months_between(to_date(dend, 'mm/yyyy'), to_date(dstart, 'mm/yyyy')) + 1;

RESULT
-------
01/2019
02/2019
03/2019
04/2019
05/2019

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a PL/SQL procedure and some test code.

```sql
DECLARE 

    PROCEDURE p_list_months(start_date IN DATE, end_date IN DATE) AS
         v_count INTEGER := 0;
    BEGIN
        v_count := MONTHS_BETWEEN(end_date, start_date);
        FOR i in 0..v_count LOOP
             dbms_output.put_line(to_char(add_months(start_date, i),'mm/yyyy')); 
        END LOOP;
    END;


BEGIN
   p_list_months(SYSDATE, ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, 5));
END;
```

And a SQL query:

```sql
-- start_date 10/2019 end_date 10/2020
SELECT to_char(add_months(TO_DATE('10/2019','mm/yyyy'), LEVEL-1), 'mm/yyyy') dat 
    FROM dual 
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (MONTHS_BETWEEN( TO_DATE('10/2020','mm/yyyy'),
                                          TO_DATE('10/2019','mm/yyyy'))) + 1;
```